# View Controllers deinitialized still memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, deinit

I have `deinit` method in all my VCs to check if they are being deinitialized or not

```
 deinit {
        print("\(self.description) successfully deinitialized")
    }
```

When I logout, I see all my view controllers are deinitialized and my `LoginViewController` becomes the root view controller. But I can still see the RAM usage as **90MB**. Every time I log in and logout, it keeps increasing.
Is it possible if my view controller has deinitialized, still it can have a memory leak?

What I know is, if the view controller is deinitialized, there is no memory leak. If there is a memory leak, the view controller will not deinitialize.

Am I wrong? Please help.

**UPDATE:** As per Luca's suggestion, and with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664845/1761687) answer, I found out the memory leaks. But I am not able to understand any of this. Is there any way to make it more readable?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with `I have called deinit method in all my VCs`? Are you actually `calling` them? Because that would be wrong.

Comment: no I mean I have declared them . I will correct the sentence

Comment: Good, then I guess you are leaking other objects. You should run `Instruments` to figure out which objects.

Comment: @LucaAngeletti Thanks will try Instruments. Never used it before. **What I know is, if view controller is deinitialized, there is no memory leak. If there is memory leak, the view controller will not deinitialize.** And also, am I correct here?

Comment: Yes but this applies to other objects too. Any instance of a class could be leaked. Most likely you have a `strong retain cycle` which is preventing some instance(s) from being deallocated.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664845/1761687) is related to SpriteKit but the process is pretty similar in UIKit. Hope it helps.

Comment: @LucaAngeletti I tried it. I managed to get the memory leaks. Is there any way to make it more readable ? its quite complicated to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three types of undesired memory issues:

1. **Abandoned memory:** This is memory that you do have some lingering strong references, but for which you no longer have access to these references. The typical example is a strong reference cycle.

   This is very common problem in Swift projects. You find these using the “Debug Memory Graph” feature. See [iOS app with ARC, find who is owner of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14104556/1271826) or [How to debug memory leaks when Leaks instrument does not show them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30992338/1271826).

   By the way, you’ve apparently confirmed that your view controllers are being released. That’s great if that’s the case. But they’re not the only object that can be entangled in a strong reference cycle. Any reference types can get caught up in reference cycles. Use the “Debug Memory Graph” feature and review your objects in the left panel and make sure there’s nothing there that shouldn't be. (By the way, this technique saves you from having to sprinkle `deinit` methods all over the place.)
2. **Cached memory:** This is memory that has been allocated, and the system will hang on to it in case you might need it again, offering you high performance access. This often isn’t too worrisome unless the amount of memory consumed is huge, because when the device is placed in memory pressure, often this memory is reclaimed automatically for you.

   If you use `UIImage(named:)` that can cache images in memory. If you use `URLSession`, the `URLCache` can cache responses.

   If testing on simulator, you might want to choose “Debug” » “Simulate Memory Warning” and see how much memory is retrieved, if any.
3. **Leaked memory:** This is memory that that has been allocated, but for which you have no further references to it. Typically this is a result of some manual allocation of memory that was never deallocated.

   The Leaks tool will help you find these, but this is relatively uncommon to have anything material in this category in Swift code. (Or if you do have them, they tend to be small things generated within the frameworks, not within your control.) Sure, if you’re doing manual Core Foundation (or Core Graphics) calls, you can manifest these sorts of issues, but it’s not very common.

   FWIW, the leaks tool doesn’t appear to be reporting any material memory consumption. So focus on Allocations tool (or, better, the “Debug Memory Graph”, if you can). Your leaks don’t appear to be enough to account for the sort of memory loss that you’re talking about here.

Also, I’d suggest you confirm that you do not have memory diagnostics turned on. E.g. things like zombies or the like can cause growth in memory (though I wouldn’t have thought that you could approach 90mb worth). Tools like this, the malloc stack trace, etc., increase memory consumption. That’s fine while using these tools to diagnose issues, but should be turned off when you’re done.

But, bottom line, I’d focus on confirming that the problem is not abandoned or cached memory, before diving into leaks (as often the latter are small and unrelated to anything in your code). These are far more common source of issues.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the ViewController is de-initialised it doesn't necessarily mean it will be deallocated. There is a possibility there is a strong reference cycle. Or maybe in your code, to avoid retain cycle you are using `unowned` reference somewhere, for which the reference count is not becoming zero. The object will not be de-allocated until both **strong** and **unowned** reference counts become zero. In that case try using `weak` instead of unowned and see if it works. Weak references point to something called [side table](https://medium.com/@deekshakaul1/memory-management-in-swift-6028e6a8976c#db8a) instead of directly pointing to the object, and hence don't keep the object from getting deallocated once de-initialised

Check out [this article](https://medium.com/@deekshakaul1/memory-management-in-swift-6028e6a8976c) to understand how unowned reference can sometimes keep the object from getting deallocated, and ARC in general.